# Why does Ethereum Wallet download new binary for Geth (I'm already running Geth)?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have geth running already on my computer with `datadir` and `ipcpath` flags. I then run Ethereum Wallet with corresponding flags to link the two. But as EW is starting up it still downloads geth again (then a moment later connects to the node I am already running).

And even if I didn't already have geth running... I thought EW had a geth binary already packaged in with it?

```
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.423] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.425] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.425] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.426] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.507] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - Unable to resolve Geth executable: geth
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.510] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Download binary for Geth ...
[2017-06-14 09:16:54.512] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Downloading package from https://gethstore.blob.core.windows.net/builds/geth-darwin-amd64-1.6.5-cf87713d.tar.gz to /Users/studio3/Library/Application Support/Ethereum Wallet/binaries/Geth/archive.tar ...
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.228] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - md5
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.229] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - 57b04bd0d24b41534f97861250af165b
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.229] [ERROR] ClientBinaryManager - 57b04bd0d24b41534f97861250af165b
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.592] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.607] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.607] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.713] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"/Users/ETHUSER/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"}
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.717] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
[2017-06-14 09:17:07.718] [INFO] NodeSync - Ethereum node connected, re-start sync
```